# Separating data from middle of CSV file WITHOUT using row numbers in script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[Spreadsheet in Question](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zdsu_YfktTrO8T-1FDCyW_RsnDE-KFfNdsWsFlRws1w/edit?usp=sharing)

My energy supplier outputs a rather confusing CSV file with data under multiple unhelpful headers within one sheet. Only one type of data is necessary to me ("E1 Data").

I want to create a script that automatically separates the relevant data (between rows 244-485 in this version). However, these row numbers change each day when updated as more data are added to each section.

The headers for each section are consistent every time CSV is updated, could I create a script to sort data based on the text in this header (currently on row 244)?

> 200   6102111110  B1E1K1Q1    **E1    E1**        DZ152889    KWH 30

It would have to be some sort of script specifying the values ***between***     the above header ("E1 data") and the "K1" header (row 486).

Not sure if this is possible, but I'm brand new to creating scripts. Tried to do my due diligence with research first!

Otherwise could I create a script that calculates the row E1 data will start at and uses this value? I've come up with a formula on the spreadsheet that shows how these row numbers could be found, but unsure how to make a script based on this!

Here is a script that works for this current spreadsheet, but wouldn't for any other days, as the rows would change:

```
function CopyE1Data() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var destination = ss.getSheets()[1];

  var range = source.getRange("A245:AX485")
  range.copyValuesToRange(destination, 1, 2, 2, 2);
  
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column `A` seems to specify the type of the row. Using that we can detect the headers (value 200), and searching for `E1` in the fourth row we can detect that header. Here’s the script I came up with (rundown at the end)

```js
function CopyE1Data() {
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 const source = ss.getSheets()[0]
 const dest = ss.getSheets()[1]
 const rows = source.getRange(1, 1, source.getLastRow()-1, 4).getValues()
 
 // Find the rows
 let i = 0
 let start
 let end
 while (i < rows.length) {
   if (rows[i][3] === 'E1') {
     start = i + 2 // +1 to skip the current row (only copy data) and +1 to convert from index to row number
     break
   } else {
     i++
   }
 }
 // The current row is the E1 header. Skip it.
 i++
 while (i < rows.length) {
   // Stop at next header or at the end of the sheet
   if (rows[i][0] === 200) {
     end = i + 1 // +1 to convert from index to row number
     break
   } else {
     i++
   }
 }
 
 // Copy values
 source.getRange(start, 1, end-start, 50).copyTo(dest.getRange(1, 1))
}
```

### Rundown

1. We get the sheets and the data necessary (4 columns; all the rows)
2. We search for the row with `E1` in column 4. Save the next row (we don’t copy the header).
3. We skip this row and continue iterating until we either find another header or reach the end.
4. Copy the values to the other sheet.

You may want to get the sheets by name instead of using the index, as it would allow you to change the order and add other sheets before them.

### References

- [Range copyTo(destination) (Google Developers)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)
- [Sheet getLastRow() (Google Developers)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
- [Range getValues() (Google Developers)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Spreadsheet getSheetByName(name) (Google Developers)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method.

[setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) sets a rectangular grid of values keeping the original format.

```
function extractData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const source = ss.getSheets()[0];
  const dest = ss.getSheets()[1];
  const lr = source.getLastRow();
  const arrE1 = source.getRange(1, 4, lr, 1).getValues();
  const fE1 = [].concat(...arrE1); // Make the array flat
  let rE1 = fE1.indexOf("E1") + 2; // Search for the starting row's number of the range with the required data
  
  let arr200 = source.getRange(rE1, 1, lr, 1).getValues();
  let f200 = [].concat(...arr200); // Make the array flat
  let r200 = f200.indexOf(200); // Search for the ending row's number of the range with the required data
  
  let data = source.getRange(rE1, 1, r200, 50).getValues();
  dest.getRange(2, 1, data.length, 50).setValues(data);
}
```